# Content-Disposition setting for Apache Tomcat 8

Tags: apache, http, tomcat

In web.xml file of apache tomcat located at `"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\conf\web.xml"`, we can set the `Content-Type` of http header.

I need to also set `Content-Disposition`, what and where the changes are required for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a Filter.

An UrlRewriteFilter may help you.
https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/AddOns